# How to set a parametr in the contructor of injection service?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a service, in which I inject another service with parametr in constructor.

Main service

```
export class Test1Service {
    constructor(
        test2Service: Test2Service
    ) {}

    getIndex() {
        console.log(111);
    }
}
```

Inject service

```
@Injectable()
export class Test2Service {
    item;

    constructor(name) {
        if (name === 'blog') {
            this.item = 'item1';
        } else {
            this.item = 'item2';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fot this will change providers import in module:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    Test1Service,
    {
      provide: 'BLOG',
      useValue: new Test2Service('blog'),
    },
    {
      provide: 'ANALYTICS',
      useValue: new Test2Service('analytics'),
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Use it in service

```
@Injectable()
export class Test1Service {
    constructor(
        @Inject('BLOG') public testBlog: Test2Service,
        @Inject('ANALYTICS') public testAnalytics: Test2Service
    ) {}

    getIndex() {
        this.testBlog.getIndex()
        this.testAnalytics.getIndex()
    }
}
```